# Getting 1st element of string type in emacs lisp

Tags: string, properties, emacs

I am trying to handle some data my little emacs helper program retrieves.

This is what the data structure look like:

```
#("[[id:b6f64bd1-3bf8-4a15-ad50-46bc5d5d1c94][Subsub1]]" 43 50 (fontified nil line-prefix #("**" 0 2 (face org-indent)) wrap-prefix #("***** " 0 2 (face org-indent) 2 6 (face org-indent)) face org-level-1 org-category "dummy")))
```

I am interested in getting the first element, i.e. the string `"[[...]]"`.

Letting some functions investigate the data, does not really reveal the trick:

```
;; initiailize helper var
(setq dummy  #("[[id:b6f64bd1-3bf8-4a15-ad50-46bc5d5d1c94][Subsub1]]" 43 50 (fontified nil line-prefix #("**" 0 2 (face org-indent)) wrap-prefix #("***** " 0 2 (face org-indent) 2 6 (face org-indent)) face org-level-1 org-category "dummy")))

;; check type
(type-of dummy) ;; => string (for some reason unknown)

;; check length
 (length dummy) ;; => 52 (#o64, #x34, ?4)

;; get substring
(seq-subseq dummy 45 52) ;; => #("bsub1]]" 0 5 (fontified nil line-prefix #("**" 0 2 (face org-indent)) wrap-prefix #("***** " 0 2 (face org-indent) 2 6 (face org-indent)) face org-level-1 org-category "dummy"))

(seq-subseq dummy 50 52) ;; => "]]"
```

All this does not really make sense to me. From documentation, I'd assume that the construct `#(..." determines some vector.

But `(seq-elt dummy 0)` would not return the string I am looking for.

Can someone please provide some hint about this string datatype or even some direction about how to retrieve the first element of the data structure.

Comment: Question is unclear. What do you mean by the first "element" of a string? Its first character? First property in its list of properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Common Lisp, Emacs Lisp doesn't use `#(...)` for vectors, it uses `[...]`.

In Emacs Lisp, there is a [`#(`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Text-Props-and-Strings) syntax for strings:

```
#("characters" property-data...)
```

It does look as if the data you are retrieving might be of this form. There is a manual section on working with strings with text properties.

I see there is a `propertize` function which converts a regular string to one with properties.

Use the [`substring-no-properties`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Creating-Strings) function to extract plain string data from it, without properties.

Comment: Just to emphasise: the original object *is* a string, and anything you want to do with a string can be done with that object directly.  You may still want a no-properties version, but you don't *need* to do that unless the inclusion of the properties presents some kind of problem.